# Loss is Nan - PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to train a simple neural net with the following architecture:

```py
class ModifiedNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_inputs, num_outputs):
        super(ModifiedNet, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(num_inputs, 1000)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(in_features=1000, out_features=num_outputs)

    def forward(self, input):
        input = input.view(-1, num_inputs) # reshape input to batch x num_inputs
        output = self.linear(input)
        output = self.linear2(output)
        return output
```

The dataset is MNIST (`num_inputs=784` and `num_outputs=10`).

I'm trying to plot the loss (we're using CrossEntropy) for each learning rate (0.01, 0.1, 1, 10), but the loss is NaN when I reach LR=1.

From looking at similar questions, I saw that you're supposed to lower the LR, but my task  is to measure it with the given ones.

What am I doing wrong?

This is the code for the train and test:

```py
# train and test functions
def train(epoch, network, optimizer=None):
    losses = list()
    network.train()

    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data, target = Variable(data), Variable(target)
        if optimizer is not None:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        output = network(data)
        loss = F.cross_entropy(output, target).to(torch.float64)
        losses.append(loss.item())
        loss.backward()

        if optimizer is not None:
            optimizer.step()

        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, batch_idx * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * batch_idx / len(train_loader), loss.item()))
    return np.mean(np.array(losses))
            
def test(network):
    network.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    for data, target in test_loader:
        #data, target = Variable(data, volatile=True), Variable(target)
        output = network(data)
        test_loss += F.cross_entropy(output, target, reduction='sum').to(torch.double).item() # sum up batch loss
        #test_loss += F.cross_entropy(output, target, sum=True).item() # sum up batch loss
        pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1] # get the index of the max log-probability
        correct += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).cpu().sum()

    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
    print('\nTest set: Average loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))
    return test_loss
```

and this is where I'm looping over the learning rates:

```py
learning_rates = [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]

for learning_rate in learning_rates:
    net = ModifiedNet(num_inputs, num_outputs)
    optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    train_losses = dict()
    for epoch_idx in range(10):
        train_losses[epoch_idx] = train(epoch_idx, net, optimizer)

    plot_graph(list(train_losses.keys()), list(train_losses.values()), "epoch", "train loss", str(learning_rate))
```

And this is the original question:

> Retrain the model for 10 epochs with each of the learning rates in the
> set {0.01, 0.1, 1, 10} and test the resulting model. Create a figure
> and plot the loss curves of each of the four runs for comparison.
> Explain the obtained (train and test) results.

Also, the net architecture is a given in the question, so I can't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a silly bug as usual, and didn't use an activation function.